# Want to create a bootable CD with Linux to run/install on an old Thinkpad iseries 1300-1171! I have to create the CD on my Mac (Catalina)

Tags: boot, mac, thinkpad, cd

If somebody would help, I think this is a light version that could permit to get rid of windows 2000 on this very old Thinkpad and use it.
I suppose I can't install latest version because of the minimal hardware, so which version and how?
Also, as I don't have the choice to boot from usb drive (Thinkpad), I need it on CD.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think any Ubuntu will fit on a cd. You are better off creating a 3Gb-ish partition and to put the ISO in there and then boot from grub into that partition. You need 32-bit but all OSs that support that are off topic here (debian, mint, gentoo, opensuse all support 32-bit). If you want a CD: DSL/damn small linux fits on a business card ( http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/ ) This question should be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ since you get an answer there for ANY Linux system

Comment: If I was you I'd spend a 200 euro for a 64-bit machine ;-)

Comment: He wants to resurrect an old machine. I'm doing this with old thinkpads. It is not easy but fun. But you're right - this is not the right forum for it... and no current Ubuntu (32bit) will ever run on a pentium 3 in a decent speed.

Comment: You need to use a USB or DVD for live media.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for a 32 bit version of linux (AntiX [download](https://mirrors.evowise.com/mxlinux-iso/ANTIX/Final/antiX-19/) for example) since your Thinkpad can not cope with a Ubuntu 64bit system. Do not install gnome- it will be to heavy on your resources.

There are other distros out there (also [puppy](https://puppylinux.com/) is recommendable) that might fill this great peace of hardware with life.

To get it on cd just download the iso file and burn it onto a CD.

**EDIT**

I've looked up the specs. Your device is a PAE PIII processor, so the Ubuntu flavours will be too heavy on this device. A stripped down MXLinux/AntiX should work

Comment: Seems a good solution, thank you.   Will the CD be bootable on the Thinkpad? and I will be able to format hard drive and install Linux on?

Comment: @Jack, remember that if you chose to install a non-Ubuntu based distro, you will not be able to ask questions about it on AskUbuntu, and you will need to seek support on the distro's support site. Nevertheless, this is a very old laptop, and I doubt that even "lighter" official Ubuntu distros (Lubuntu or Xubuntu) will run on this machine.

Comment: Yes got it, it is normal.  I was going toward Ubuntu but if there is no 32 bit light version, I will try another distro..

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: @Jack you will find a lot of instruction on how to "burn" that iso onto the cd. I've done it with my old Thinkpad A 21 - if the answer helped you, I'd appreciate if you could accept it

Comment: Both Lubuntu and Xubuntu have 32 Bit ISOs. The nice thing is, you can try them in a live environment to see if they work, before installing. However, I think only the Lubuntu ISO will fit on a CD. Lubuntu 32 Bit is 715 MB ISO (http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04-alternate-i386.iso). Xubuntu 32 Bit is 1.55 GB ISO (https://torrent.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/bionic/release/desktop/xubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-i386.iso.torrent).

Comment: @PJ Singh You are right. Certainly thought it wouldn't exist anymore. I'll try it with my old Thinkpad 42.. Thanks for the tip

Comment: As described in my answer. A Pentium 3 is certainly not supported by the flavours mentioned above

Comment: Answers need to be about official Ubuntu's.

Comment: @kanehekili & PJ Singh...  Thanks guys for the ideas.  I am pretty busy all week so I'll give it a try next week and let you know.  Thanks again for your help, appreciated.